# Restoring request parameters in @ViewScoped bean after session expires

Tags: jsf, restore, view-scope, http-request-parameters, viewexpiredexception

I have a page that has the setup as below with url like `my.page.com/table.xhtml?id=123`:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|Meta information                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
|           Search Fields           Submit btn |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|                                              |
|            Big p:dataTable                   |
|                with rowExpansion             |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                   Pager                      |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

`id=123` is the request parameter that controls the content on the result table.  All actions only reload the data table using `AJAX`.

`id` is loaded throught this :

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{dataTable.id}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{dataTable.initialize}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This all works fine, until the session expires.  At this point, nothing works.  I cannot get data since I no longer have access to the `id` in question and the call to the `DAO` classes fetching the data do not have this.

By "***no longer have access to the `id`***" I mean that :

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")
```

returns `null`.  Also, the `int id` from my backing bean (which is loaded through the `o:viewParam` in the `f:metadata` suffers the same fate.

I know there are methods to catch a `ViewExpiredException`, but this is not what I want.  I need the page to simply reload all values using the request parameter (in this case `id`) without the user knowing.

I (think I) need a `@ViewScoped` manage bean to control this complex table and all parameters, etc.

I am at a lost with regards to this.  I have tried building my own `ViewHandler` to try to get it to simply rebuild (mimic a refresh) of the page, and tried to use the `PrimeFaces` `ajaxExceptionHandler` among other solutions.  But all these get an error and display it.  I just want to have access to my request parameter `my.page.com/table.xhtml`**`?id=123`** from the backing bean.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am running on:

- Tomcat 7
- Mojarra 2.2.6
- Omnifaces 1.8.1
- Primefaces 5.0

Comment: What does "no longer have access to the id in question" mean?

Comment: @EJP updated the question with more details with regards to the question you had.

Comment: That happens because of the Ajax calls. Session expiry has nothing to do with request parameters. Store it in the view or a bean with a c:set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to bypassing the expired view by just completely recreating it, add [`<o:enableRestorableView>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/enableRestorableView) to the metadata:

```
<f:metadata>
    ...
    <o:enableRestorableView />
</f:metadata>
```

As to retaining the request parameter, *either* add a plain HTML hidden input field to the form:

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="#{dataTable.id}" />
</h:form>
```

*or* use [`<o:form>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form) with `includeViewParams="true"`,`includeRequestParams="true"` or `useRequestURI="true"`, depending on whether you'd like to submit to the JSF view ID with all view params, or to the JSF view ID with the entire request query string, or to the entire request URI (including query string):

```
<o:form includeViewParams="true">
    ...
</o:form>
```

As to reinitializing the bean's state on postback before it going through all phases of the JSF lifecycle, you'd need to replace the `<o:viewParam>` by manually grabbing it and the `<f:viewAction>` by `@PostConstruct`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    id = Faces.getRequestParameter("id");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When doing as stated above, and say clicking a `commandLink` on the pager, the error is hidden and the page displayed, but I lose all data.  The data is not refreshed and the `actionListener` never called.  I end up losing all the data - basically what is `update`d.

Comment: Update puts me on the right track.  A few extra things I need done, but that's more specific functionality/logic to be done on my end.  Thank you!

Comment: I didn't get the right answer i tried <f:metadata>
    ...
    <o:enableRestorableView />
</f:metadata> with the <h:form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="#{dataTable.id}" />
</h:form> also i tried <o:form> but the problem i have multiple form in the page but not nested those didn't solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these above and not working in mojarra 2.2.5

Just change mojara to mojarra 2.2.8 and it will be solved without adding any code