# View parameter and @ViewScoped bean: recover after server restart

Tags: view-scope, jsf-2.3, viewparams

Supposing following scenario:

- In a web application I have a simple form on a page where the user can update a value in a database; the backing bean `Controller` is `@ViewScoped`. The object which holds the value is read from database in a custom converter when the page is loaded using a GET parameter.

```html
<!-- The details page for editing an object -->
<f:metadata>
  <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{controller.myObject}" required="true">
    <f:converter converterId="myObjectConverter" />
  </o:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
<o:form includeViewParams="true">
  <h:inputText id="desc" value="#{controller.myObject.myValue}" validatorMessage="Input invalid">
    <f:validateRequired />
    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />                        
  </h:inputText>
  <p:message for="desc" />
  <h:commandButton action="#{controller.updateValue()}">
    Save
  </h:commandButton>
</o:form>
```

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

  // Getter/setter omitted
  private MyObject myObject;

  @PostConstruct
  public void onPostConstruct() {

  } 

  public String updateValue() {
    // Persist myObject and return to list page
    return "objects.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + myObject.getId();
  }
}
```

- Now the user navigates to this page, but does not click the button to submit the form and keeps the browser window open
- Meanwhile the server restarts (note: `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD`is set to `client`)
- When the server is up again, the user wants to submit the form
- In that case the controller bean's `@PostConstruct` will be called, but as expected the member `myObject` will not be set by the converter resulting in NullPointer access.

So is there any suggested JSF-way to handle such a scenario? I hope I have expresses myself clearly...

Comment: Does a session scoped bean survive a restart?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394142/restoring-request-parameters-in-viewscoped-bean-after-session-expires help?

Comment: For me when using Tomcat and OpenWebBeans, while restarting the Tomcat sessions get persisted and restored. The @PostConstruct is not invoked again for viewScoped beans, irregardles of state_saving_method server|client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same behavior on a @SessionScoped bean and the server is cleaned and restarted. Thanks for the link, it helped a lot.

It seems to me that the only solution is to hook into `@PostConstruct` and check if the member is null. In that case I simply have to re-initialize the view by myself (which would be by default done using a converter).

```java
@PostConstruct
public void onPostConstruct() {

  if (Faces.isPostback() && this.myObject == null) {
    // Load object from database
    final long requestId = Long.valueOf(Faces.getRequestParameter("id"));
    setMyObject(objectService.get(requestId));
  }
}
```

Is this a correct assumption: When I would have had some additional validators on the view parameter `id` they do not to have checked explicitly in `@PostConstruct` because the postback request transports the "original" `id`-value, so this *must* be a previously validated value, so it cannot be tampered by the user?